# Jquery conflict when two of the same on one page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm having a conflict with a jQuery feature im adding to a wordpress backend. There will be the option of adding two of these features to a page, but when there is two, the first one works and the second one doesnt. They both HAVE to share the same classes and ID's

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/39/

HTML

```
<div class="plugin">
<div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>
<span id="selectedIcon" class="selected-icon"></span>

<button id="selectIconButton">Select Icon</button>
<div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list">
    <div id="iconSearch">
        <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
        <input type="text" name="icon-search" value="">
    </div>
    <span class="icon-orange"></span>
    <span class="icon-teal"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
    <span class="icon-tealer"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 50px"></div>


<div class="plugin">
<div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>
<span id="selectedIcon" class="selected-icon"></span>

<button id="selectIconButton">Select Icon</button>
<div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list">
    <div id="iconSearch">
        <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
        <input type="text" name="icon-search" value="">
    </div>
    <span class="icon-orange"></span>
    <span class="icon-teal"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
    <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
    <span class="icon-tealer"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
var iconVal = $(".icon_field").val();
$('#selectedIcon').addClass(iconVal);

$("#selectIconButton").click(function () {
  $("#iconSelector").fadeToggle();
});

$("#iconSelector span").click(function () {
  selectIcon($(this));
});

function selectIcon(e) {
 var selection = e.attr('class');
 $(".icon_field").val(selection);
 $("#iconSelector").hide();
 $('#selectedIcon').removeClass();
 $('#selectedIcon').addClass(selection).show();
 return;
}

$('input[name="icon-search"]').keyup(function(){
  var sValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

$.each($('span'), function(){
    if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(sValue)===-1){
     $(this).fadeOut(0);   
    }else{
     $(this).fadeIn(0);   
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: If you give two elements the same "id" value, all bets are off, and jQuery simply will not work properly.

Comment: @OGDEV1990 - It's the HTML DOM that won't allow multiple elements to have the same ID. No amount of jQuery or JavaScript will fix that.

Comment: I get it. I managed to fix some of it but not things are just going haywire. http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/43/

Comment: You're still re-using ids.  Rather than using ids, assign classes, and then try researching sibling selectors, or restructure your HTML so that you can use child selectors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is pointed out clearly in the comments.  `ID` must be unique on any given page.  `id="iconSelector"` - just add this as a class along with `icon-list` so it will look like `class="iconSelector icon-list"`.  By using standard jQuery selector techniques you should still be able to interact with the DOM as needed.

> They both HAVE to share the same classes and ID's

This requirement is illogical.  You'll have to rework your process.

A little advice to help you along the way - you can utilize `$(this)` to know which DOM element has triggered an event - so you don't need to worry about `ID`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the classes or element types rather than the id's.  Add classes if necessary.  For example,

```
$('#selectedIcon').addClass(iconVal);
```

becomes

```
$('.selected-icon').addClass(iconVal);
```

--

```
$("#selectIconButton").click(function () {
  $("#iconSelector").fadeToggle();
});
```

becomes

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $(".icon-list").fadeToggle();
});
```

As mentioned in the comments you cannot use multiple ids.

Full example:

HTML

```
<div class="plugin">
    <div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>
    <span id="selectedIcon" class="selected-icon"></span>

    <button id="selectIconButton">Select Icon</button>
    <div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list">
        <div id="iconSearch">
            <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
            <input type="text" name="icon-search" value="">
        </div>
        <span class="icon-orange"></span>
        <span class="icon-teal"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
        <span class="icon-tealer"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 50px"></div>


    <div class="plugin">
    <div class="iconDisplay">Display's selected icon</div>
    <span id="selectedIcon" class="selected-icon"></span>

    <button id="selectIconButton">Select Icon</button>
    <div id="iconSelector" class="icon-list">
        <div id="iconSearch">
            <label for="icon-search">Search Icon: </label>
            <input type="text" name="icon-search" value="">
        </div>
        <span class="icon-orange"></span>
        <span class="icon-teal"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon3"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon4"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon5"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon6"></span>
        <span class="icon-icon7"></span>
        <span class="icon-tealer"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
var iconVal = $(".icon_field").val();
$('.selected-icon').addClass(iconVal);

$("button").click(function () {
  $(this).siblings(".icon-list").fadeToggle();
});

$(".icon-list span").click(function () {
    selectIcon($(this));
});

function selectIcon(e) {
    var selection = e.attr('class');
    $(".icon_field").val(selection);
    e.parent().hide();
    e.parent().siblings('#selectedIcon').removeClass();
    e.parent().siblings('#selectedIcon').addClass(selection).show();
    return;
}

$('input[name="icon-search"]').keyup(function(){
   var sValue = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $.each($('span'), function(){
        if($(this).attr('class').indexOf(sValue)===-1){
         $(this).fadeOut(0);   
        }else{
         $(this).fadeIn(0);   
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: There's some progess, but still things are going haywire! http://jsfiddle.net/yQMvh/43/

Comment: There's still some using id's in there, such as $("#iconSelector span") which should be $(".icon-list span").  There are others too ;)

Comment: Try this one for size - http://jsfiddle.net/j4aS7/7/ - is that what you're after?

Answer (score 0):

It's not super fancy, but is this the functionality you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/ccarterc1984/RfW69/

CSS:

```
#iconSelectionBox{
    width:250px;
    height:250px;      
    background-color: gray;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;          
}
#icon1{
    background-color:blue;        
}
#icon2{
    background-color:black;        
}
#icon3{
    background-color:green;        
}
#icon4{
    background-color:purple;        
}
.icon{        
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    float:left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="iconSelectionBox">
    <input type="text" id="searchBox" /><br/>
    <div id="icon1" class="icon"></div>
    <div id="icon2" class="icon"></div>
    <div id="icon3" class="icon"></div>
    <div id="icon4" class="icon"></div>
</div>

<button class="selectButton">Select Icon</button>
<button class="selectButton">Select Icon</button>

<br/>
<div id="messageBox"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button.selectButton').live('click', function(){
    var iconBox = $('#iconSelectionBox');
    var buttonPos = $(this).position();

    iconBox.show().css('top', buttonPos.top + 100).css('left', buttonPos.left);
});

$('div.icon').live('click', function(event){
    var clickedId = event.target.id;

    $('#messageBox').text("You clicked the icon with id: " + clickedId);

    $('#iconSelectionBox').hide();
});
```